# How to generate multiple buttons that have the same intent but have another Extra

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, layout-inflater

Im trying to generate multiple Views in eclipse with LayoutInflater. The button also has an OnClickListener with it and it works. The intent starts and i give it an extra.

But what i want is that a button keeps it own extras. Saying the first button has extra: number 1 the second has 2 and so on. At the moment al the buttons get the same extra, number 5. Because when i try to get the intent extra in com.example.http WIZARD it always says 5

```
 String[] title = {
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5"
    };

LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout insertPoint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_content);
List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++){
    View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.single_task, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    Button bStartWizard = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bStartWizard);

    textView.setText("Opdrachtnummer:" + title[i]);
    titleString = "Opdrachtnummer:" + title[i];

    bStartWizard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.http.WIZARD");
            i.putExtra("Number", titleString);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    views.add(view);
}

for(int i = 0; i<views.size(); i++){
    insertPoint.addView((View) views.get(i));
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Button bStartWizard = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bStartWizard);**

I think you're having a problem here since you want to generate 5 buttons with same button ID on the xml, so the **onclicklistener** will try to get the last value assigned to the button which is 5, try to generate different ID's for each buttons.

check this code on creating buttons, manipulate the values

```
Button bStartWizard = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_game_option_button, layout, false);
```

Comment: What excactly do you mean with the parameter: layout?